# Wrist Wraps on both wrists?

Tags: workout, injury-prevention, wrist

One of my wrists is weaker than the other.  I am working on strengthening both of my wrists, but I want to protect my weaker wrist while I workout. Should I use wrist wraps on the weak wrist or both wrists?

Comment: what kind of workout are you trying to do?  What are you wrapping your wrist for?  I.E. pullups, deadlifts, benchpressing, basketball ?

Comment: IMO only using one-strap will eventually lead to [muscle asymmetry](https://www.google.ca/search?q=muscle+asymmetry&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2K4GUYfzCoyn0AG_0IDIAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=683)

Comment: @DavidR  Pushups(ie.handstand, crawl,normal), pullups, benchpressing..

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc That is one of my worries.

Comment: Are you feeling pain in your weaker wrist when you workout without the wrist wrap?

Comment: @DavidR Yes. It not all time but usually once a month after workout handstand push-up or heavy pulls-up.. I will have pain in my wrist for a week or so. So I am trying to protect it during those workouts & Strengthen the wrist during the week with wrist exercises & stretching

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are doing handstand push-ups and "heavy pull-ups"? As-in, pull-ups with added weights, and you are worried about your wrists?  Maybe you should just stick to normal exercises.........

Comment: I hesitate to officially answer, because I can't do either HSPUs or weighted chins (with any significant weight).  But if it were me, I'd focus on fixing my wrists.  And either doing these feats of strength less frequently, and / or supplement them with exercises that don't hurt your wrists (barbell press, dumb bell rows, so forth) until you've sorted out your wrist issues.  My $0.02.

Comment: I do, however, do some rock climbing (but no gymnastic exercises).  My experience there is that trying to patch over joint pain with a brace just never works out the way I'd want it to.  Its always better to just be patient and address the underlying issue. YMMV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: when you are experiencing recurring pain that lasts for weeks during your workouts, then you should definitely consider getting a doctor or physical therapist to check it out. The rest of my answer is going to assume that you got the "all-clear" from your doctor and that this is in fact nothing more than a muscular imbalance in your wrists.

To me it sounds like the exercises you are doing are too intense for your weaker wrist to handle, thus the pain. I would scale back on the intensity level and gradually build up wrist strength before attempting to do these exercises at the intensity level you are at now. Additionally, you may want to consider adding some supplemental grip strength exercises to your routine to expedite the recovery. Here are some exercises that will help you build wrist strength:

1. Deadlifts. [See this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9904/will-grip-strength-automatically-increase-with-deadlift/) for advice on building grip strength as your deadlift progresses.
2. Tennis ball squeeze. Put a tennis ball in your hand, squeeze it as hard as you can, then release.
3. Wrist curls. Get a very light dumb bell (maybe 1-5 lbs to start), hold it at a 90 degree position to your upper arm with your palm facing up, then curl the weight without moving the forearm (only the hand and wrist will move).

As far as doing your current exercises, using a wrist wrap is totally fine, and as you scale in intensity it can often become a necessary tool in order to avoid injury. On your build up sets I would recommend forgoing the wraps, and only using them on your work-sets / exercises that are giving you problems. That being said, wraps can become a crutch that prevent grip strength from developing, and will lead to eventual degradation of wrist strength in relation to the rest of the muscles.

As for using one or both, I would personally stick with both. For one, if the weak wrist is experiencing pain from the exercise, chances are the other wrist isn't too far away either. Second, by using only one wrist wrap you will be developing the muscles asymmetrically.